# why two different IP address for wlan and eth

Tags: networking, ip, ip-address

I have several doubts regarding IP addeesses. I used 'ifconfig' to find my IP. but there was two different IP address entries for wlan and eth. why is so ?? isn't IP unique for a computer ? how is IP to a machine assigned ? isn't IP assigned during manufacturing of a computer?

Answer (score 1):

Because they are different network devices.

Regarding your other questions in the contents, Google is the best tool.